# Trying to increment a MariaDB value

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-trigger

I am trying to increment value using a trigger in MariaDB. However, for some reason, the value does not increment each time the row is updated. I can confirm that the row is being updated every 1 minute via Cronjob.

**The PMA trigger:**

[image]

Essentially here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I am trying to take the old playtime value and increment by 1 each time the the row is updated.

So for example, if a row has a playtime value of 200 and the row is updated, it'll now become 201.

Any ideas? I have been stuck on this for a long while. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER` so we can see the entire text of the `TRIGGER`.  What you provided leaves us guessing what that UI does.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want:

```
new.playtime = new.playtime + 1;
```

That seems really strange, though.  Why would you have a query that incremented an incoming value by 1?

Comment: I am using it on one of my game servers to track playtime through a web application. The web application determines 1 as a new minute, and assembles the time into readable text (i.e. It'll print 100 minutes as "1 Hour and 47 Minutes").

Comment: Also that does not appear to work after testing it. What I am trying to do is take the old value and increment it by 1.

Comment: @Blizzard098 . . . This is almost certainly NOT the way to approach this.  You would need to ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: I edited the question to include what I'm trying to accomplish, and I also gave an example.